# Show that the following tautology is a theorem of natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

I'm struggling to apply the theorems of natural deduction to these two examples.

$$((p \to q) \land (p \to \neg q)) \to \neg p$$

$$((p \to q) \land (p \to r)) \to (p \to (q \land r))$$

Can anyone help? That is, soundness and/or completeness.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just answering homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: I tried to follow the formula and I think I understand the rules that are necessary to complete the theorem, but I am finding hard to apply them to real case examples. Especially I am having trouble knowing what to assume, reiterate, derive etc.

Answer (score 3):

I won't write natural deduction tree, but make a sketch of the proof.

- (( ⟶ )⋀( ⟶ ¬)) ⟶ ¬
  To prove the implication, you fist assume ( ⟶ )⋀( ⟶ ¬). To get
  ¬, you assume  and get a contradiction by getting both ¬ and .
- (( ⟶ )⋀( ⟶ )) ⟶ ( ⟶ (⋀))
  Again, to prove an implication, you assume the antecedent ( ⟶ )⋀( ⟶ ). From this asummption you can get ( ⟶ ) (*) and ( ⟶ )(**)  separately. Now you need again to prove another implication  ⟶ (⋀), so you assume  and get both  and  by using (*) and (**) with